# Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

Tags: javascript

When I run the code below, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

```js
for(var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    var heads='head'+n;
    var image="images/"+heads+".jpg";
    console.log(heads);                
    document.getElementsByClassName('horse2').style.background="url("+image+")";
}
```

```css
#results .horse1 { background-image: url(images/head1.png); }
#results .horse2 { background-image: url(images/head2.png); }
#results .horse3 { background-image: url(images/head3.png); }
#results .horse4 { background-image: url(images/head4.png); }
```

```html
<table id="results">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1st</td>
        <td class="horse1"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1st</td>
        <td class="horse2"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1st</td>
        <td class="horse3"></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your fourth element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers.

You should use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('horse2')[0].style.background="url("+image+")";
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('horse2')` this will return an array of elements. You should use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('horse2')[0].style.background="url('img-url')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should aware that getElementsByClassName selector returns an array so you need to supply the index for it , change your code to this :

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('horse2')[0];
el.style.background = "url("+image+")";
```

Answer (score 0):

> [`Document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an **array-like object** of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

It is important to note two things:

1. An array-like object is a regular object with a `length` property, and  properties with sequential numerical names starting at 0. Other than that, it has none of the other methods of a normal array, though it has a couple of its own.
2. The array-like object returned by `Document.getElementsByClassName` is a "live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)", which means that as elements are added and removed from the DOM, so too will they be added to or removed from the collection.

`Document.getElementsByClassName` will never return a single element by itself, it will always return a live `HTMLCollection`.

You have a few options (minor variations may not be mentioned):

1. Iterate the collection (unnecessary if there will only ever be one element of each class):

   ```
   var collection = document.getElementsByClassName('horse2');
   for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
       collection[i].style.background = "url("+image+")";
   }
   ```
2. If there will only ever be one element, the recommended way would be to use an id instead of a class then use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), which returns a reference to a single element with the supplied ID.

   ```
   document.getElementById('horse1').style.background = "url("+image+")";
   ```
3. If there will only ever be one element and you need to use classes, but you don't need to use `Document.getElementsByClassName` specifically, you can instead use [`Document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which returns the first [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('.horse1').style.background = "url("+image+")";
   ```
4. If there will only ever be one element and you must use `Document.getElementsByClassName`, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to select the first element in the collection

   ```
   document.getElementsByClassName('horse1')[0].style.background = "url("+image+")";
   ```

   However, if there ever happens to be no elements in the collection, there will be no first element to select, and you will get the same error all over again.